# How to make the text break in phrases?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm building a responsive site. Due to the fact that the css has a range between 320 and 480px, I am having an issue that the text is breaking at single words and not at phrases.  I am not sure if this can be accomplished with css. I assume that javascript will be required.

I'll attempt to diagram what's happening:

It breaks at each word.

```
-------------------------------------------
| phrase one bla bla bla > phrase two bla |         
| bla > phrase three bla                  |
-------------------------------------------
```

What I need is it to break after each phrase.  I want it to look like this:

```
-------------------------------------------
| phrase one bla bla bla                  |         
| phrase two bla bla > phrase three bla   |
-------------------------------------------
```

I have included a symbol ">" between the phrases. It would also be great if the symbol would be eliminated if it is at the end of the line.

Comment: *Talk is cheap, show me the code* please!

Comment: Try wrapping each phrase in a span tag with display:inline-block

Comment: Well, how the browser is going to know where phrase ends? So you need to insert either wrapping container like span, or add new lines or br's.

Comment: @dfsq: The browser knows the end of each phrase due to the symbol ">" I have place in between the phrases (as stated above). So this is actually the reference breaking point.

Comment: @Mimi: Well the actual html code would be `<address>Korkisch Haustechnik GmbH | Auhofstraße 120A | 1130 Wien | Tel.: 01/877 25 25 | Öffnungszeiten: Mo–Do: 7.00–17.00 Uhr | Fr: 7.00–13.00 Uhr </address>`. And I need it to break at the "|" character and not in between. Thx.

Comment: @Rickkwa: I just tried your suggestion and it works. Just the "|" that is inbetween needs to be deleted after the break. But thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your HTML, within each phrase, replace the spaces with the HTML entity `&nbsp;` (which stands for Non-Breaking SPace):

```
phrase&nbsp;one&nbsp;bla&nbsp;bla&nbsp;bla phrase&nbsp;two&nbsp;bla&nbsp;bla phrase&nbsp;three&nbsp;bla
```

The spaces between phrases should be ordinary (breaking) spaces.

Answer (score -1):

What you need is an HTML-tag called break.

```
<br>
```

your solution may look like this:

```
<p>phrase one bla bla bla
   <br>phrase two bla bla
   <br>phrase three bla.</p>
```

more info here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp